# Visual Studio Form Won't Open In Design Mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The form is listed in the Solution Explorer and it appears when the program runs, but I can't open it in design mode. The icon beside the form is also different from the rest of my forms.

How can I open it in design mode?

[image: screenshot showing items listed in solution explorer]

Comment: Kind of strange...Maybe make sure you are in "design mode", that is the solution is not running. Also try to shut down (and maybe save) the current solution and open it again. Assuming that you are the only person using this solution. Also make sure the file is not open by another editor or in another window of VS.

Comment: It's not in use by anyone else (I'm the only one using it), I have closed the project and visual studio and reopened it. 
I don't know what you mean by "make sure you are in "design mode"". I have the project open and I'm able to view other forms in the same project in design mode. The icon beside the form is different and I feel like that is relevant but I don't know how or how to fix it.

Comment: By "design mode" I mean that you are not running the project or debugging it. I guess there is a chance that it corrupted. Try to copy the form to a new form (with different name) and see if the new one would open.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It was not running or debugging. I will try to copy it. I may just recreate it. I was trying to figure out what caused the issue.

Comment: I assume that this is very unusual. Note that the VS Form Designer creates files containing the code and it uses this code to render the controls. If the files are removed or the contained text is altered manually in a wrong way, the form would not be openable. However, you are supposed to get a message if this is the case when you double click on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but it just happen to me.
The issue I had was that I declare a class above the form class definition. it seems that it makes the IDE confuse and recognize the file as a class not as a form class, after I moved the class to a separate file I was able to open the form in design mode and the icon changed. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After comparing a previous version of my solution I found that Visual Studio had somehow changed some project settings. Unload your project and look at the  tag for the form. My current, non working version had:

```
<Compile Include="frmFileNotes.cs" />
```

The previous working version had:

```
<Compile Include="frmFileNotes.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

After manually updating the project forms with the  tag, my forms started displaying again.

No idea how that happened, but all the forms in that project had the Form removed.

Comment: Note also, if it is a user control that is not displaying, I had a couple of other changes that VS seemed to make. Non working version of a user control:

    <Compile Include="CShotGridCtl.cs" />

Working version:

    <Compile Include="CShotGridCtl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>